# How to find website api to extract graph data?

Tags: r, api, web-scraping, data-extraction

https://www.okx.com/markets/spot-data/btc-usdt  .  I'd like to extract the data using R. Although I found a similar post on stackoverlfow to do this. I can't seem to find the API for this website. I checked all the XHR files and there is no link? does that mean it's hidden? I only want the api for the " BTC Margin lending Ratio"

Thanks.

Comment: from your comment, I assume they don't have it? I'm not familiar with APIs that's why I created this post. Does this mean it is not public? And there is no way of extracting the data?

Comment: I don't know if they have a public API.  Whether or not they do is really a [sales / customer service question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745) and is better addressed to the company.  It's certainly possible that they do have one but it is only available from behind a paywall.  That being said, at the bottom of the linked page there is a link **Service [V5 API](https://www.okx.com/docs-v5/en/#overview)** which may be useful.

Answer (score 1):

The XHR requests fetch the data as json to make the graph. It's pretty straightforward to parse this and replicate the plot.

To make it more useful, you can wrap this in a function that takes a start date and (optional) end date and returns a data frame with a date and value column:

```r
get_BTC_loan_ratio <- function(from, to = as.character(as.Date(Sys.time()) - 1))
{
  from <- as.character(from)
  to <- as.character(to)
  base_url <- "https://www.okx.com/priapi/v5/rubik/stat/margin/loan-ratio?"
  from <- paste0("&begin=", from, "T00:00:00Z")
  to <- paste0("&end=", to, "T23:00:00Z")
  url <- paste0(base_url, from, to, "&period=1D&ccy=BTC")
  df <- setNames(as.data.frame(jsonlite::fromJSON(url)$data), c("Date", "BTC"))
  df$BTC <- as.numeric(df$BTC)
  df$Date <- as.POSIXct(as.numeric(df$Date)/1000, origin = "1970-01-01")
  df[order(df$Date), ]
}
```

For example, to get a data frame of daily values since 1st January we can do:

```r
BTC <- get_BTC_loan_ratio(from = "2022-01-01")

head(BTC)
#>                    Date     BTC
#> 163 2022-01-01 16:00:00  2.4766
#> 162 2022-01-02 16:00:00  2.9682
#> 161 2022-01-03 16:00:00  5.1275
#> 160 2022-01-04 16:00:00  3.6736
#> 159 2022-01-05 16:00:00  3.5300
#> 158 2022-01-06 16:00:00 17.6896
```

And we can plot it like this:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(BTC, aes(Date, BTC)) +
  geom_line(color = "deepskyblue4") +
  theme_light(base_size = 16) +
  scale_x_datetime(date_labels = "%d %b % %Y")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: thanks a lot, Allan. I actually found one of your similar answers for this but couldn't find the link after I pressed f12. Appreciate it.

Comment: Would it be possible to access data not listed on the website? I meant data from previous months.

Comment: @raistlinn see my update. Effectively this function acts as an API, though it is limited to the last 6 months of data as far as I can tell. This is the data source that the web page uses, so unless you find a different data source, this is as much as you can extract from this particular site.